# Override 30 seconds timeout on gem class timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, thin

My thin server is timing out after 30 seconds. I would like to override this ruby file.

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT from 30 seconds to 120 seconds. how to do it? Please let me know.

code is here: 
https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/server.rb

I would like to override without "already initialized constant" Warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the help

```
➜  ~/app ✓ thin --help | grep timeout
   -t, --timeout SEC                Request or command timeout in sec (default: 30)
```

So you can change it from the command line when starting the server

```
➜  ~/app ✓ thin --timeout 60 start
```

or you can set a config file somewhere like `/etc/thin/your_app.yml` with something like this

```
---
timeout: 60
```

and then run thin, pointing it at this YAML file with

```
thin -C /etc/thin/your_app.yml start
```

---

As a side note, you should consider if increasing your timeout is really necessary. Typically long running requests should be queued up and run later through a service like [`delayed_job`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [`resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque)

---

After seeing your comment and learning you're using Heroku, I suggest you read **[the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)**

> Occasionally a web request may hang or take an excessive amount of time to process by your application. When this happens **the router will terminate the request if it takes longer than 30 seconds to complete**. The timeout countdown begins when the request leaves the router. The request must then be processed in the dyno by your application, and then a response delivered back to the router within 30 seconds to avoid the timeout.

I even more strongly suggest looking into delayed_job, resque, or similar if you're using Heroku. You will have at least one worker running to handle the queue. [HireFire](http://hirefire.io/) is an excellent service to save you money by only spinning up workers when your queue actually has jobs to process.

Comment: you mean put --> --timeout 120 in procfile of rails? my app is on heroku so I am not sure where to type the command line while starting the server?